# How Do I Make A Small jQuery Confirm Replacement?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, confirm

I have a table row with a Delete link on it for deleting that row. I want to create a jQuery feature that pops up above that Delete link an "Are you sure?" yes/no confirm dialog, but in ***a very small size***.

How do I achieve this in the ***least lines of code*** in jQuery?

I mean, I need to **determine the x,y of the Delete link** that was detected from a click, and then move (and fadeIn()) a DIV into that location. **If they click anywhere on that page except Yes on the yes/no**, the thing does a fadeOut(). If they click Yes, then it deletes the row with a fadeOut() effect.

***Note on this I don't need a modal screen dimmer, but the confirm needs to work modally.***

(Items above that are bolded are something I don't exactly know how to do. Items bolded and italicized are important to what I need to do.)

I would think a widget like this would be critical to any Web 2.0 design, much like the [Pines Notify](http://pines.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pines/trunk/pnotify/index.html) feature seems essential.

Answer (score 1):

See **[jQuery Impromptu](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php)**. There you can find a lot of samples.

Comment: Do you know of anything like this, but more like what I'm asking for, and in less lines of code?